# Automapper: Leave collections without their mapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

Given the next DTOs:

```
public class OrderDTO{
    public int IdOrder{ get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDTO{
    public int IdProduct { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is i want to Map an **Order** to a **OrderDTO**, but sometimes, i don't need to fetch the **Products**.

When i need all, i do the next:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>().ForMember(
    dest => dest.Products,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(
        // Custom Map the Product with ProductDTO
        order => order.Products.Where(n => n.Active).Select(
            aProduct => new ProductDTO{
                IdProduct = aProduct.IdProduct,
                Description = aProduct.Description
            }
        )
    )
);
```

It work's great, but the problem is when i don't need the **Products**, i do the next:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()
```

But it returns an error:

> Missing map from Product to ProductDTO. Create using
>   Mapper.CreateMap.

So, how can i do for avoiding creating a Mapper for a collection i don't need?? (I don't want to retrieve data from the database i don't need).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create another DTO, named like `OrderWithoutProductsDTO` or `BasicOrderDTO`, which will not have products

```
public class OrderWithoutProductsDTO
{
    public int IdOrder{ get; set; }
    public int TotalPrice { get; set; }    
}
```

That will allow you to skip hitting products in order entity (and thus lazy-loading them) and it also will not confuse people, who will use your `OrderWithoutProductsDTO` - nobody will wonder why there is empty list of products. Mapping will simply look like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderWithoutProductsDTO>();
```

One more hint - if you will define mapping for product and product DTO, then you don't need to map them manually:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Products,
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(o =>
                  Mapper.Map<List<ProductDTO>>(o.Products.Where(n => n.Active)));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a solution, because i'd have a lot of DTO's because this was an example, but i have a DTO with 8 subcollections of DTO's, so calculate the total possible combination of dtos i should have...

Comment: @ArielScherman and why you want to load all possible combinations? E.g. if you will have order with customer, collection of products, collection of discounts, collection of comments and billing address. Why would you want OrderWithCustomerButWithoutProductsAndDiscounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore a property.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Products, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Edit:
I think you are trying to do that because of performance reasons, but please consider not to do it. First, don't create mappers very often, because it's CPU intensive and in high load you will get 100% CPU easily. Second, I'm pretty sure that automapper has a internal cache, given a object with same information it doesn't performance the mapper, it returns a cached object. Also, it has cached mapper and you are just destroying it.

Said that, please consider other option if that is what you really want to do. Like another DTO as @Sergey Berezovskiy suggested.

Comment: But in that case OP will have opposite problem - mapping with products will not work

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to avoid one ignore per collection i don't need! Isn't there any way for setting the ignore option to every collection as default?

Comment: I just edited my answer, I really suggest you to read it. Please try to explain us why you are trying to do it? Avoid micro optimization.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, you're right, but he is creating a new map every time I believe. Well, if product is null from Order, he will have no problem, so maybe treat it before the mapping?

Comment: @BrunoCosta well, that will be really costly to create mappers each time :) Usually you should create them once for whole application

Comment: I know, I just said that :P. Ok, another option is to clone an order object and set product list to an empty list or something similar to this if he really wants to keep the same object and not returning the product information.